# como hacer un scroll automatico, autoincrementable con javascript para un sitio web por consola

Tags: javascript, html5

Como hacer un scroll automático, autoincrementable con JavaScript para un sitio web por consola.

Buenas, he visto un código donde lo ponian por la consola de la página y este bajaba solo sin necesidad de aplastar el botón del centro del mouse. ¿Me podrían ayudar a encontrar el código? Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar `window.scrollBy` y `setInterval` para lograr un scroll automático. Puedes ajustar el período para cambiar la velocidad. No estoy seguro de a qué te refieres con 'autoincrementable'.

```
setInterval(() => {window.scrollBy(0,1)}, 10)
```

Comment: ¡Muchas Gracias! No recordaba como hacerlo.